# Which graphs do have invertible adjacency matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, inverse, spectral-graph-theory

I would like to know if there is any class of graphs for which the adjacency matrices are invertible. At this moment I am aware of o[nly the class of graphs $n K_2$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3588) which is the disjoint union of $n$ number of $K_2$ matrices where the adjacency matrices are self-inverse.

Are there any other classes?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188600/on-the-invertibility-of-adjacency-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a permutation $\pi$ of a finite set $V$, form its cycle graph $G$ as follows: the vertex set is $V$ and the edges are pairs $(v,w)$ for which $\pi(v)=w$. (This is a simple directed graph.) The adjacency matrix will in fact be the permutation matrix corresponding to $\pi$, which is invertible.

We can also form graphs with loops whose adjacency matrices are upper triangular: take the vertex set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and adjoin edges $i\to j$ as one wishes but only when $i\le j$ (and of course make sure every vertex has at least one loop).

Comment: Are there any other classes?

Comment: @OmarShehab Yes, for instance $[\begin{smallmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}]$. A complete classification would seem to characterize all invertible matrices with nonnegative integer entries, and I am not aware of such a characterization (although I haven't looked). My guess is it'd be unlikely there is a strictly graph-theoretic characterization of these graphs, but you'd have to ask a graph theorist to be more confident.

Comment: Just asked a supplementary question at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/graph-isomorphism-problem-with-invertible-adjacency-matrices

Comment: For the first class of graphs, the adjacency matrices are always involutory, right?

Comment: I am not sure what definition of 'cycle graph' you are using here. According the the definition in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph), a cycle graph can have only one cycle. In that case, there cannot be any cycle graph for the permutation $(1 2)(3 4)$, right?

Comment: Is there a standard name for the first class of graphs?

Comment: @OmarShehab I don't know what the term in graph theory would be or if there is one (it would seem the term "cycle graph" that graph-theorists use is a more restrictive notation), but I'm almost certain I have seen the term "cycle graph of a permutation" used for this construction in the theory of combinatorial species (a mixture of combinatorics, permutation group theory and category theory).

Comment: So, for your definition, a cycle graph is a disjoint collection of cycles, right?

Comment: The cycle graph *of a permutation*, specifically, is what I defined in my answer, yes.