# Class of all graphs with invertible adjacency matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This question is a generalization of the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469024/which-graphs-do-have-invertible-adjacency-matrices).

From the answers of the questions, I can list four classes of graphs which have invertible adjacency matrices.

1. [The class of graphs $nK_2$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3588)
2. Given a permutation $\pi$ of a finite set $V$, its cycle graph $G$ can be defined as follows: the vertex set is $V$ and the edges are pairs $(v,w)$ for which $\pi(v)=w$. This is a simple directed graph. The adjacency matrix will be the permutation matrix corresponding to $\pi$, which is invertible. The class of all such graphs.
3. Graphs with loops whose adjacency matrices are upper triangular: we take the vertex set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and adjoin edges $i\to j$ as one wishes but only when $i\le j$ (and of course we have to make sure every vertex has at least one loop).
4. [Graphs with adjacency matrices which are diagonal with non-zero entries](http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math109/hw6.pdf)

Is there a systematic way to generate the group of all invertible adjacency matrices?

Comment: *"Can we formally define a class of all graphs with invertible adjacency matrices?"* - Of course you could.  Why wouldn't you be able to?  You can define anything you like.  I don't think I understand your question.  What exactly is your question?  What are your thoughts, and what is your specific confusion/uncertainty?

Comment: @D.W., I am afraid I didn't clarify it. The question should have been "Is there a systematic way to generate the group of all invertible adjacency matrices?"

Comment: I encourage you to edit the question to whatever it should be / should have been.  Make sure you define what you mean by "systematic way to generate a group".  And do some self-study: e.g., the group of invertible matrices is a standard group with lots written about it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group.

Comment: @D.W., I just found that the General linear group over $\mathbb{Z}$ is what I should be studying.