# What properties does a graph whose adjacency matrix is invertible have?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, inverse, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I was thinking about adjacency matrices, when I realised that an adjacency matrix is nilpotent if and only if there is no cycle in the graph.

So, I started wondering: **if a graph has an adjacency matrix that is invertible, what does it mean for the graph?**

I usually define a graph the following way (but if the is some proprieties with another definition, I'm also interested): a graph $G=(V,E)$ is couple of set where $V = [\![1;n]\!]$ and $E \subset \{ (i,j) \in V^2, i\neq j$}. The adjacency matrix $M=(M_{ij})$ is defined such as $M_{ij} = 1$ if $(i,j) \in V$, $0$ otherwise.

Here I'm talking about undirected graphs.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're talking about directed graphs specifically here? The undirected case is asked already at at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188600/on-the-invertibility-of-the-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph

Comment: Yes I'm talking about undirected graphs. I'll make it clear in my post!